# Power BI - DirectQuery with parameters?

Tags: powerbi

For a practice purpose, I am building a Power BI report based on one of my Crystal reports. I wonder if the Power BI report can ask for parameter inputs like the Crystal reports, and if it is possible, how do I import the query with the parameters?

For example, with a Crystal report, I would add the following query into the Command section, and the Crystal report would ask me to enter the parameter inputs prior to executing.

```
Select * 
from myTable
where date between {?StartDate} and {?EndDate}
```

How would the power BI take it?

Answer (score 0):

This may address your question: "[Create and use what-if parameters to visualize variables in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if)"

Comment: Sorry. Not quite.